# swift moving and releasing object with touch

Tags: swift

I'm new to coding. I have created a scene in swift sprite kit with a ball and floor.  When executed, the ball drops and bounces on the floor. I am looking for a bit advise on how to move and drop the ball with touches.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Are you looking to move the ball to the position of a touch? Or do you want to do something else entirely?

Comment: move the ball with finger when released the ball drops to the floor

Answer (score 3):

To detect drag ball you have to create UIPanGestureRecognizer and add it to the ball's view

`let dragBall = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"dragBall:")
 ball.addGestureRecognizer(dragBall)`

Next step is implementing "dragBall" function which will handle drag event, example:

```
@IBAction func dragBall(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
  let point = recognizer.locationInView(self.view);
  ball.center.x=point.x
  ball.center.y=point.y
}
```

You should also disable gravity for this object for time of dragging, you can check if Pan gesture ended by checking state of gesture recognizer, if state is UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded you should add gravity again

Answer (score 0):

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        ball.position = CGPoint(x:500,y:500)
        ball.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0,y:0.0)
        ball.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)

        // physics
        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 1)
        // this defines the mass, roughness and bounciness
        ball.physicsBody.friction = 0.2
        ball.physicsBody.restitution = 0.8
        ball.physicsBody.mass = 0.1
        // this will allow the balls to rotate when bouncing off each other
        ball.physicsBody.allowsRotation = true
        self.addChild(ball)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
    { ball.position = touches.anyObject().locationInNode(self); }


    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

by the end of the day i worked out this bit of code but it seems very hard to keep hold of ball

Comment: Check out this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/44270/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites